# Why this resize handler is not working?

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/57org2ve/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="at" style="width:100%;background:red">
This is a div, you can click on me or resize me. 
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#at').resize(function(){alert(1)})
$('#at').click(function(){alert(2)})
```

Comment: I know $(window) only use to resize but in your case the element want to resize event. i also looking for the solution

Comment: I believe the resize event is only usable on window object, so you would need to use `$(window).resize()` but it seems more like you want an event fired when the user changes the size of the element directly?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want a resize event on the element.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/jquery-resize/v1.1/jquery.ba-resize.js found this trick but it's 6 years ago.... I don't know whether there's any better ways....

Comment: Could you tell me how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a little function which check onresize if the width of element has changed. Resize the browser and check out console log result.

```js
$(window).resize(function(){

  var obj = $('#at')[0];
  if(detectResize(obj)) console.log('resize detected');

});


function detectResize(getObject){
  var getWidth = getObject.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  if(getObject.currentWidth===getWidth){
    return false;
   } else {
     getObject.currentWidth = getWidth;
     return true;
   }
}
```

```css
#at{
  width:100%;
  max-width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="at" style="background:red">
This is a div, you can click on me or resize me. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to refer this link

http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

I have just checked with this js this is worked for me download this file and check it ,hope this will help you

```
var element = document.getElementById('at');
new ResizeSensor(element, function() {
   console.log('Changed to ' + element.clientWidth);
});
```

Comment: Upvote for something I find interesting.